# How to find file with name="php.ini" on linux using grep command

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

How to find file with name="php.ini" on linux using grep command ? Can anybody show me ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You would normally use `find` not `grep` to find files by name.

```
find / -name php.ini
```

If you must use grep

```
cd /; ls -lR | grep php.ini
```

In both cases replace "/" with the absolute or relative path for the directory you wish to start the search in.

Note that linux also has a `locate` command that relies on indexing - check it's man page for details. This is fastest if the right locations are indexed.

Comment: To search within the current directory, use `find . -name php.ini`. To ignore case, use `find . -iname php.ini`. To search for directory names, use `find . -iname bin -type d`.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add some more information...

```
find / -name php.ini
cd /; ls -lR  | grep php.ini
```

of course do work, but you could be better served with

```
locate php.ini
```

which uses the indexed filesystem database to locate the file. It is considerably faster. To update the filesystem index, the command is:

```
updatedb
```

These however required root as far as I remember.

*disclaimer: I have not used linux for years for anything meaningful... I learnt these back then when the predominant distribution was slackware, and debian potato was not even out...*

Comment: I think you were writing this at the same time I was updating my answer with the same idea :-)

Comment: Yes, Heh, I beat you by 3 minutes. +1 to you for the same great idea :P

Answer (score 0):

`fs all | filter "php.ini"`

or 

`fs "**/php.ini"`

when you install

`npm install nixar`

More docs: http://nixar.work/doc

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question, which was asking about using `grep`. In addition your link is broken (it returns a blank page).